# Exporting a list to Matlab

Tags: export, matlab

I have some parameters.

```
parameters = {c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 1}
```

I want to export them to Matlab using [`ToMatlab`](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/).

```
    <<ToMatlab`
parameters /. Rule -> Equal // ToMatlab
```

The code above gives:
[image]

I want to get:

```
c=1;
    d=1;
    e=2;
    f=1;
```

---

**EDIT:**
If I have the following parameters:

```
parameters2 = {a[1]->5,c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 1}
```

How to get the following?

```
 a(1)=1;
    c=1;
    d=1;
    e=2;
    f=1;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `ToMatlab`? Did you load this from a package?

Comment: Yes, I loaded it using `<<ToMatlab` `

Comment: Once again, the question is careless. Package `ToMatlab` isn't a built-in package. Indeed, experienced users know it, but not everybody knows. You should provide the link to the package in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parameters2 = {a[1] -> 5, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 2, f -> 1};

StringReplace[
  StringRiffle[
    StringJoin[ToString[#], ";"] & /@ (parameters /. Rule -> Equal), 
    "\n"
  ],
  {"==" -> "=", "[" -> "(", "]" -> ")"}
]
(* Out: "a(1) = 5;\nc = 1;\nd = 1;\ne = 2;\nf = 1;"  *)
```

[image: screenshot of the output]

Comment: Yes, it is almost what I want. If I have one more parameter such as `a[1]->5`, how to get `a(1)=5;` ?

Comment: @RF_1 that wasn't mentioned in your original question. Please avoid changing the goalpost in your questions.

Comment: You are right. I transformed the question into original version.

Comment: Could you help me for my second question in the comments above? Many thanks for your interest

Comment: @RF_1 See the updated version of my answer.